# My machine as Wi-Fi Hotspot broken after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04, hot-spot

I use my Ubuntu machine as a wifi hotspot: it is wired to my ADSL modem and uses its wifi card as a hotspot.

Upon upgrade to 20.04 from 18.04 the hotspot stopped working. I have tried reconfiguring several times without success. All appears normal when doing so, but the network doesn't work.

[image]

Symptoms are different depending on the OS of the client:

1. Ubuntu: the network shows up but will not connect
2. MacOS:  the network will connect but there will be no internet
3. Windows 10: the network will connect but there will be no internet

I reported [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1870359) on the issue about a month ago without any progress.

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: I noticed the `iptables` needed for the hotspot to work are not set when the hotspot is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in 20.10 breaking the hotspot feature. Installing updated packages listed [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1870359/comments/6) will solve the problem.

Note that there is [another bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1879122) that make the hotspot appear unconfigurable ("Turn On WiFi Hotspot..." is grayed out). To work around this bug you must click a different setting category (like "Baground") before returning to Wi-Fi settings. Now clicking on the three vertical dots at the top will reveal "Turn On WiFi Hotspot...".